# HttpUrlConnection - cache data for offline

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm building an Android app that works with a web server available only from a local network. Outside, even I have an Internet access, I'd like to be able to have some available data. My needs are:

- write downloaded data to the local cache ***each time I'm able to access to the webserver***
- read data from the cache ***only when the connection to the webserver is not available***.

I think I know how to proceed manually by handling file reading and writing manually but I'd like to know if it's possible to do this with the Java class `HttpUrlConnection`. Here is basically how I connect to download data:

```
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

I read a lot of documentation about that class but it's still a bit confusing for me. I was initially thinking about using "setDefaultUseCaches(true)" but I first don't know if that is enough to cache data and I don't want the app to use cached data if the connection is available.

Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` may be older than you are. I recommend using a modern networking library, one that offers built-in caching. [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) is a common choice, and it offers [an integrated cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#response-caching-kt-java).

Comment: you can store data in sqlite (for table or large data) or shared preferences for small data.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Looks like much easier than HttpUrlConnection.